# SheetJS read excel file, my file is not read

Tags: javascript, excel

So I am trying to use the SheetJS javascript to read in some excel files. I download the SheetJS and I have copied the xlsx.full.min.js in same directory as my html file. However, I do not get it to work. So I tried the code below. The problem is that it does not reach the alert('finished reading'); line. So I do not know if there was a problem reading the source file or what the problem exactly is. I hope somebody can help me with this! Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p><input type="file" name="xlfile" id="xlf" /> ... or click here to select a file</p>

<script src="xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
<script>

   function handleFile(e) {
     //Get the files from Upload control
        var files = e.target.files;
        var i, f;
     //Loop through files
        for (i = 0, f = files[i]; i != files.length; ++i) {

            var reader = new FileReader();
            var name = f.name;
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                var data = e.target.result;
                alert(data);
                var result;
                alert('reading now');
                var workbook = XLSX.read(data, { type: 'binary' });
                alert('finished reading');
                var sheet_name_list = workbook.SheetNames;
                sheet_name_list.forEach(function (y) { /* iterate through sheets */
                    //Convert the cell value to Json
                    var roa = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[y]);
                    if (roa.length > 0) {
                        result = roa;
                    }
                });
               //Get the first column first cell value
                alert(result[0].Column1);
            };
            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(f);
        }
    }
var xlf = document.getElementById('xlf');
if(xlf.addEventListener) xlf.addEventListener('change', handleFile, false);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you check the console. What error is it showing?

Comment: Try this link http://oss.sheetjs.com/js-xlsx/

Comment: Yes I read that link but I am beginner and I am trying to figure out how I can do some basic reading. Thank you for the hint I was not aware I could just check the console in my browser. It indicates the following error:
    xlsx.full.min.js:22 Uncaught TypeError: x.charCodeAt is not a function
    at firstbyte (xlsx.full.min.js:22)
    at Object.readSync [as read] (xlsx.full.min.js:22)
    at FileReader.reader.onload (testing.html:29)

Comment: I use Chrome. Do you have any idea how I can solve this. I was reading on internet but I do not find an answer.

Comment: Please share the code in JSfiddle, I will work on it an correct that for you. Or the best way is to copy the source code from the link that i shared and use it./

Comment: Thanks man! I tried the code you suggested and found out that I had a problem with the paths of the javascript files.

Comment: Great!! you are good to go

Comment: Ok it works now but I cannot figure out how to access the cells of a worksheet. So in the end you get for example output = to_csv(wb) or to_json. But how can i access the cells of the sheets?

Comment: You need to add logic in javascript to read the JSON object and access the cells